# Webpack 4 Split Chunks Terms

Tags: javascript, webpack, code-splitting, webpack-4

I understand the great work that was done on webpack 4. Specially on rewriting the code splitting plugin. 
However, and since it's still kinda new, I don't find good documentation on the new SplitChunksPlugin.

I struggle on the meaning of the terms chosen. For example:

**chunks**: there are 3 possible values "initial", "async" and "all". What does it mean? Initial chunks are the entries? Async the dynamic imported? all is the initial + async? If I use initial then my dynamic imported chunks won't leverage the code splitting? Eg. main.tsx dynamically imports about.tsx which does a normal import of lodash. Lodash wouldn't be extracted to the vendors bundle?

**enforce**: I see a lot of configs setting the enforce:true, what does it mean?

For a better context I'm posting an example of splitChunks configs.

```js
optimization: {
    splitChunks: {
      cacheGroups: {
        'commons': {
          minChunks: 2,
          chunks: 'all',
          name: 'commons',
          priority: 10,
          enforce: true,
        },
      },
    },
  },
```

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, while actually there is some official documentation: https://webpack.js.org/plugins/split-chunks-plugin/

The following article might be more useful: https://medium.com/webpack/webpack-4-code-splitting-chunk-graph-and-the-splitchunks-optimization-be739a861366

I particularly find the following very enlightening:

> The new chunk graph introduces a new object: the `ChunkGroup`. A `ChunkGroup` contains a `Chunks`.
>
> At an entrypoint or an async splitpoint a single `ChunkGroup` is referenced, which means all containted `Chunks` in parallel. A `Chunk` can be referenced in multiple `ChunkGroups`.
>
> There are no longer parent-child relationships between `Chunk`, instead this relationship now exists between `ChunkGroups`.
>
> Now “splitting” of `Chunks` can be expressed. The new `Chunk` is added to all `ChunkGroups`, which contain the origin `Chunk`. This doesn’t affect parent relationships negatively.